# Creating Android APK file online form PHP site

Tags: android, command-line, build-process, apk

i am developing android application builder web site, I have issues with assigning APPS ICON and application name Dynamic from json, Do you have any ideas? I can give more information over discussion. Here  it is http://mbdbtechnology.com/projects/softlab/
Member can signup and build their own simple application , simple TABS etc.i am creating JSON objects with querystring with different site IDs and compiled to APK file
I have two issues at the moment how can i assign application ICON to new renamed APK file ?
do you have any other alternatives to achieve this , please help me out
first you refer http://www.appsgeyser.com and http://beta.appinventor.mit.edu i have same concept like this site. i want to create APK online as per user requirement.

Comment: why you're asking the same question again?

Comment: my first qustion is closed so

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-cmdline.html